# How to visualize data row wise as a pie chart ?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

how can representation of data can be plotted row wise for each row if the data is as :

```
Name Maths Science
John   87     78
Marry  76     68
Harry  98     94
```

Here,  I would like to get pie chart of each persons performance in exam row wise.

This code draws a pie chart only for 1st row, how to get a pie chart for each row ?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)    
df.iloc[0].plot(kind='pie', subplots=True, autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Comment: what python version are you running?

Comment: python 2.7 @Yuca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link on the original question suggest, just transponse your dataframe

```
df1.T.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(10, 3))
```

[image]

Comment: How about plotting a range of rows only say for `row 0 to row 5` ...how `loc[]` can be used to get a pie chart ?? @Yuca

Comment: just as you say, df.iloc[:6,:].T.plot.pie (... )

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the question is that you are using `.iloc[0]` to slice just the first row.

If you want to plot all you would either need to remove it (which I think would be better) or instead of `0`put `:`.

However, if you want to slice row 0 to 5 you you need to:

```
df.iloc[0:5].plot(kind='pie', subplots=True, autopct='%1.1f%%')
```